# Formatting Visualforce Pages in VSCode on Save

Tags: visualforce, vs-code, prettier

can someone confirm how to get prettier working with visualforce pages on save in VSCode? I have tried in a fresh project but it never works.

Steps taken:

1. SFDX: Create Project
2. npm install
3. SFD: Create Visualforce Page
4. edit and save test visualforce page - prettier doesn't run...

Settings below confirmed:

- Default formatter = Prettier - Code Formatter
- Format on Save
- .prettierrc is present

```
{
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "**/lwc/**/*.html",
      "options": { "parser": "lwc" }
    },
    {
      "files": "*.{cmp,page,component}",
      "options": { "parser": "html" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `.prettierrc` looks ok, check if you have any errors related to prettier on the output panel, you can filter the output for prettier only.

Comment: No output so looks like its being ignored?

Comment: hmm check in the package.json's script tag, if you have prettier and it should be something like this -> `"prettier": "prettier --write \"**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}\"",
  "prettier:verify": "prettier --list-different \"**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}\""`

Comment: Yep got the script and if I run from the terminal it formats correctly